# Regex match only first or only second occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find two digits in a string, but I only know whether the first two digits or the second two digits are needed, don't know where they are in the string exactly and what surrounds them. The strings are dates but the format is, for all intents and purposes, random.
I came up with this so far:

```
(?<=\D)\d{1,2}(?=\D)
```

It matches what I need, but I need to stop the matching either after the first or the second occurrence, so it won't find almost everything in these examples:

```
2019-01-05 23:59:59
2019 01 05 23:59:59
2019. 01. 05. 23:59:59
2019.01.05. 23:59:59
05-01-2019 23:59:59
5-1-2019 23:59:59
05/01/2019 23:59:59
5/1/2019 23:59:59
5 1 2019 23:59:59
05 1 2019 23:59:59
05. 1. 2019 23:59:59
5. 1. 2019 23:59:59
```

Here basically I want to match either the "1"/"01" or the "5"/"05" in every line.
I already searched a lot of forums but can't find any solution that would help, it seems everywhere the solution is dependent on the string and not exactly a "find only the nth occurrence". In my case that would really be the only thing that solves the problem, at least I couldn't come up with any patter that would definitely match every time. The examples above are not even the only possibilities, any way you can format a date is one of them, the only thing I know for a fact that it's consistent across all documents where I want to search, the date always has separators in it and it comes before the time.

Comment: Did you try it without the global `/g` flag to get only the first match? https://regex101.com/r/RTpxWx/3 Else try using an anchor and a capturing group `^.*?(?<=\D)(\d{1,2})(?=\D)` https://regex101.com/r/RTpxWx/1

Comment: The desired output would be only the month or the day from the date, depending on which one I'm looking for, so either the first or the second 1 or 2 digit number.

Answer (score 1):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/Gn0Gij/1) might help you to only get the first occurrence of your desired month and day:

```
[-\s.]+(\d{2})[-\s.]+(\d{2})[\s\S]*
```

It is not the best expression to do so, however it may give you the general idea that how this greedy chars `[\s\S]*` go through the rest of your undesired char.

You can simply change my initial boundaries as you wish, you might use your original expression with minor changes, only followed by `[\s\S]*`.

[image]

#### Graph

The graph shows how it would work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could match a 'date like' pattern and use capturing groups to extract the month or the day part. The month and day part are either in the first or third capturing group and to get a consistent delimiters you could use backreferences to the capturing groups.

To get the separate values you can split on matching not a digit `\D`

```
(?:\d{4}(([- .]|\. )\d{2}\2\d{2})\.? |(\d{1,2}([-\/ ]|\. )\d{1,2})\4\d{4} )\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
```

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d{4}` Match 4 digits
  - `(` Capture group 1

    - `(` Capture group 2

      - `[- .]|\.` Match either `-`, `/`, space OR dot and space
    - `)` Close capture group 2
  - `\d{2}\2\d{2}` Match 2 digits, backreference to group 2, 2 digits
  - `)` Close group 1
- `\.?` Match optional dot and space
- `|` Or
- `(` Capture group 3

  - `\d{1,2}` match 1-2 digits
  - `([-\/ ]|\.? )` Group 4, match either `-`, `/`, space OR dot and space
- `\d{1,2})\4\d{4}`  Match 1-2 digits, backreference to group 4 and 4 digits
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` Match the 'time like' part

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PUMtUQ/1)

For example:

```js
let pattern = /(?:\d{4}(([- .]|\. )\d{2}\2\d{2})\.? |(\d{1,2}([-\/ ]|\.? )\d{1,2})\4\d{4} )\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/;
[
  "2019-01-05 23:59:59",
  "2019 01 05 23:59:59",
  "2019. 01. 05. 23:59:59",
  "2019.01.05. 23:59:59",
  "05-01-2019 23:59:59",
  "5-1-2019 23:59:59",
  "05/01/2019 23:59:59",
  "5/1/2019 23:59:59",
  "5 1 2019 23:59:59",
  "05 1 2019 23:59:59",
  "05. 1. 2019 23:59:59",
  "5. 1. 2019 23:59:59"
].forEach(s => {
  let m = s.match(pattern);
  let res = m[1] || m[3];
  console.log(res.split(/\D+/).filter(Boolean));
});
```

As an alternative based on your pattern, instead of using a 2 positive lookaheads `(?=`, you could use 2 negative lookaheads `(?!` to assert what is on the left and what is on the right is not a digit but this will not  take the date like pattern into account.

To get only a single match you can leave out the `/g` global flag

```
/(?<!\d)\d{1,2}(?!\d)/
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZQ0sGE/1)

**Note** that the lookbehind is not widely supported and will work in Chrome.

```js
[
  "2019-01-05 23:59:59",
  "2019 01 05 23:59:59",
  "2019. 01. 05. 23:59:59",
  "2019.01.05. 23:59:59",
  "05-01-2019 23:59:59",
  "5-1-2019 23:59:59",
  "05/01/2019 23:59:59",
  "5/1/2019 23:59:59",
  "5 1 2019 23:59:59",
  "05 1 2019 23:59:59",
  "05. 1. 2019 23:59:59",
  "5. 1. 2019 23:59:59"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(/(?<!\d)\d{1,2}(?!\d)/)[0]));
```

Without the lookbehind you might use a capturing group and start the match with the start of the string `^` or not a digit `\D`:

```
(?:^|\D)(\d{1,2})(?!\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ox8oeu/1)

Comment: Negative lookbehind is only implemented in Chrome.

Comment: @Toto You are right, thank you. I have added that to the answer.